# Testing nested function in Jest

Tags: javascript, function, jestjs

I have in **file.js** code which I simplify this way:

```
function Apple(,data) {
  this.attr1 = data.attr1,
  this.attr2 = data.attr2,
  this.doSomething(data.flag);
}

Apple.prototype = new function() {
  this.function1 = function() {
    // do something
  }
  this.doSomething = function(flag) {
    // return value
  }
}
```

I want to test `function1()`, for that, I want to mock first `doSomething()` to return a specific value, but I am failing because any call to `Apple()` function executes immediately `doSomething()`:

```
describe('Apple', () => {
    test('test function1()', () => {
        Apple.doSomething = jest.fn().mockImplementation((2) => {
            // do something;
        });

        let apple = new Apple(data); // the original doSomething() executes here instead of the mocked version
    });
});
```

How can I achieve my goal ?

Comment: `doSomething` does not exist on your constructor function.It'll rather be available on your instantiated object.

Comment: So what would be the correct way to mock it ? This line `let apple = new Apple(data);` complains about `doSomething()`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try using `spyOn`:

```
const mockDoSomething = jest.spyOn(Apple.prototype, 'doSomething').mockReturnValueOnce((flag) => {
    // mock do something;
})
```